# Javascript error: "Result of expression 'el' [null] is not an object" while adding any widget to CMS content

Tags: magento

In my local dev environment, any time I try to add a widget to a CMS page I get a javascript error: Result of expression 'el' [null] is not an object.

Does anyone know what might cause that?

Magento 1.5.1
Mac OS X 10.6.7
Apache 2.2.17
Safari 5.0.5 / Firefox 3.5.9

In Chrome 12.0.742.100, the error is:
The page at localhost.com says:
Cannot read property 'selectionStart' of null

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Knowing which point in the "adding a widget to the page" process would help people track this down.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the exact same error on a v1.5.1 CE Magento system when I choose to add via the large orange 'Add Widget' button to a static block or cms page.

However, when I add a widget via the WYSIWYG editor, the widget is added as expected and I do not receive the 'el null' error.

A strange bug that will hopefully be fixed in v1.6.